# replacing the one child node value which is occurred multiple places with in the xml

Tags: xml, replace, attributes, db2

Need to replace the values 'OBLIGEE ATTORNEY' and 'saravanan' of child node <var..> by the value 'EDWIN CHAND'. THANKS IN ADVANCE
Here is the query:

```
 SELECT     XMLQUERY ( 'copy $new := $d1 
   modify (do replace value of $new/root//var[@name=$element_name] with $d)
    return $new'
                      PASSING xmlparse(document '<root>
<first>                                                                               
   <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">OBLIGEE ATTORNEY</var> 
</first> 
<second>
 <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">saravanan</var> 
</second>   
<user_input_attn_obligor_desc>OBLIGOR ATTORNEY</user_input_attn_obligor_desc>                          
</root>') AS "d1",
                              'EDWIN CHAND' AS "d",
                               'user_input_attn_obligee_desc'AS "element_name") FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

**Needed output:**

```
'<root>
<first>                                                                               
   <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">EDWIN CHAND</var> 
</first> 
<second>
 <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">EDWIN CHAND</var> 
</second>   
<user_input_attn_obligor_desc>OBLIGOR ATTORNEY</user_input_attn_obligor_desc>                          
</root>'
```

But it throws the error like below (*if xml have only one <var..> node then it works fine).*
**ERROR [10703] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL16085N  The target node of an XQuery "replace value of" expression is not valid. Error QName=err: "XUTY0008".**

Comment: Do you need a query with parameters markers? If yes, then please, edit your question to provide a couple of examples with parameter values and the result needed on this sample data above.

Comment: Hi, I changed the questions and query. could plz help me out to solve above one. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL16085N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic21.html#sql16085n), QName = err:XUTY0008

> err:XUTY0008
>
> The value of expression-type is "replace" or "replace value of" and the target node of a replace expression does not qualify any node, **qualifies a sequence of two or more nodes**, or qualifies a document node. **It must qualify exactly one node that is not a document node**.

You must iterate through the nodes, if you have multiple ones in a document.
Use the following instead:

```
SELECT 
XMLQUERY 
('
transform
copy $new := $d1 
modify 
for $xnode in $new/root//var[@name=$element_name] 
return do replace value of $xnode with $d
return $new
'
PASSING xmlparse
(document
'
<root>
  <first>                                                                               
    <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">OBLIGEE ATTORNEY</var> 
  </first> 
  <second>
    <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">saravanan</var> 
  </second>   
  <user_input_attn_obligor_desc>OBLIGOR ATTORNEY</user_input_attn_obligor_desc>                          
</root>
'
) AS "d1"
, 'EDWIN CHAND' AS "d"
, 'user_input_attn_obligee_desc' AS "element_name"
) 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much Mark Barinstein. it could be helpful if you share any Documents or web links or anything to know what are the various concepts db2 have in the xml manipulation. Thanks once  again

Comment: Great! Please, mark the question as answered then.

Comment: How to do the above one in MS SQL server?